# nagios not sending notification email

Tags: linux, nagios, snmp

Nagios not sending notification for my services. I have two service called PING and STATUS in nagios localhost.

PING service check host availability using ping command and STATUS service get the SNMP traps from remote machine.

Sometimes i getting email for PING service but STATUS service not getting any mail. PING service also not sending mail always. Below all of my configuration files.

localhost.cfg

```
define host{
use               linux-server
host_name         TESTHOST
alias             snmp_agent
address           10.10.62.5
}
define service{
use                             local-service        
host_name                       TESTHOST
service_description             PING
check_command                   mailtest
notifications_enabled           1
}
define service{ 
host_name                 TESTHOST    
service_description       STATUS  
is_volatile               1
check_freshness           1       
check_command             cagent!5        
max_check_attempts        4
normal_check_interval     1
retry_check_interval      1
active_checks_enabled     0   
passive_checks_enabled    1   
check_period              24x7    
notification_interval     20      
notification_period       24x7    
notification_options      w,u,c   
notifications_enabled     1
flap_detection_enabled    0
}
```

contacts.cfg

```
define contact{
contact_name        nagiosadmin                 
use                 generic-contact             
alias               Nagios Admin                 
email               mymail@gmail.com                    
}
define contactgroup{
contactgroup_name   admins
alias               Nagios Administrators
members             nagiosadmin
}
```

I using ssmtp mail server to send mail. configuration file below

ssmtp.conf

```
root=mymail@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
rewriteDomain=gmail.com
hostname=sujin
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
AuthMethod=LOGIN
AuthUser=mymail@gmail.com  
AuthPass=mailpassword
FromLineOverride=YES
```

Comment: fwiw, normal_check_interval and retry_check_interval are deprecated/2.x syntax.

Comment: @Keith - both options are still supported in the latest 3.5.0 core, and prob will be for some time.

Comment: yes, that's what 'deprecated' means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting emails for PING because you appear to have used your email notification command (`mailtest`) as the `check_command`:

```
define service{
    use                             local-service        
    host_name                       TESTHOST
    service_description             PING
    check_command                   mailtest       ; <<<
    notifications_enabled           1
}
```

The `check_command` for `PING` would conventionally be a `check_ping` command object.
The command to send notifications is a property of a `contact` object.

You don't have active checks enabled for `STATUS`, so Nagios will never schedule a check for that service (it will rely on NRPE or NRDP or some other external process). That's probably not what you want.

You do not appear to have associated any `contact_groups` with either your service or your host objects. However, the configuration you have added is really only *part* of the total configuration, you have not shown the default object templates, so I cannot say what has been inherited.

You seem to be having trouble understanding the Nagios object model, it's a little closer to programming than it is to configuration.
The [diagram here](http://jw35.blogspot.ie/2010/02/getting-nagged-by-nagios.html) should help you understand this problem (it's a little old, and for Nagios 2, but it's a good starting point).

The Nagios documentation is accurate but quite concise (or terse), it's not great for learning from scratch, try this tutorial: http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/nagios/index.html

Once you get a better understanding on the object concept you can peek into the `objects.cache` file and see all of your objects defined completely (this is equivalent to the configuration view in the web UI, but easier to understand if you are editing the configuration files directly).

Comment: This is good advice. It can be summed up by "read everything in The Basics section of the Nagios docs".